# How to import a java plugin into your eclipse workspace

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am working on a java plugin and I was wondering if anyone could help me.

I need to import a plugin that goes by the name of "LogBlock" and it has a lot of files if I compile it. So I was wondering if theres a way to import it into my eclipse workspace. (Decompile it and be able to edit it).

Sorry if this question is unclear, if you need any questions about this question answered just say so. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest and simplest way to go is to use JD-GUI. A super simple decompiler. Once decomplied there are 2 things you can do:
1 - Import the files into eclipse. This could take a LONG time depending on the files.

2 Recommended - Take the files pop them in a folder named LogBlock and then go to your root folder for eclipse. Open that, you should see all your eclipse projects there. Just drag and drop the folder named LogBlock. When you launch eclipse there will be your LogBlock Java Project. Open it up and you will see a ton of files. Organize them as you saw in JD-GUI.

If you need further help with this I could make a video and give you the link to it.

Answer (score 0):

[Java Decompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/) will do the trick.

[image]

From there you can import those files into Eclipse by right clicking your project, and choosing import from the options menu.  You shouldn't be editing a released plugin however..

Comment: Sorry, Christie. I meant to say I tried to use a decompiler but the file is too big to copy over to eclipse. What I meant to say is: is there a way to decompile a .jar inside of eclipse?

Comment: Sadly there isn't a way to decompile a jar in Eclipse.  You would have to go through each one of the decompiled class files and import them.  You could actually probably just import the packages that were decompiled.  Good luck

Comment: You could just decompile it in JD and click File > Save All Sources, to save the source files into a zip. Un-archive the zip and copy the source files over into your the your project folder in your workspace.